# Angular 2 - ngShow equivalent?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

According to my interpretation of the documentation, if I want to be able to have an element hidden by default, and shown when a link is clicked, the following ought to work?

1. In /app/app.component.ts

   ```
   newTrustFormVisible: false;
   ```
2. In /app/app.component.html

   ```
   <a href="#" (click)="newTrustFormVisible = !newTrustFormVisible;">[Add New]</a>

   <div ng-show="newTrustFormVisible" class="panel panel-default">
     ...
   </div>
   ```

However, this does not work. It also produces no errors. What am I missing?

Comment: I have also tried `newTrustFormVisible: boolean = false;` which I think is actually the correct syntax for that line, although it hasn't made any difference to the result.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your using Angular 1 directives. For Angular 2 use `*ngIf` for components that do not need to be in the DOM when they are hidden or bind to the HTML hidden property `[hidden]` if you want the component to always be in the DOM but hidden with CSS.

e.g:

```
<div *ngIf="newTrustFormVisible" class="panel panel-default">
```

or

```
<div [hidden]="!newTrustFormVisible" class="panel panel-default">
```

[Angular 1 to Angular 2 reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ajs-quick-reference.html)

[*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html#!#ngIf)

Comment: That's working, thanks, but it's not animated like the example in the documentation (which you're right, appears to be for AngularJS 1.x)?

Comment: animations are a separate kettle of fish see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Comment: So where ng-show would animate automatically, the closest Angular 2 equivalents do not do so. Seems odd? I have switched to ngClass as this appears easier to animate, although I've not got animation to work, yet. I'll keep playing.

Comment: If using the second technique, use this: [hidden] { display: none !important;}