# How can I hide ionic item?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have some input fields.But the input fields will show once at a time. I will get the info which one i need to show like below.

```
require_nid:false
require_pin:true
```

The from is below

```
<ion-col>
          <ion-list inset>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>
                  <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
              </ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter NID" #username required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>
                  <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
              </ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter sender Name" #password required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>
                  <ion-icon name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
              </ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter sender phone number" #password required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `*ngIf` to completely remove the element.

OR

You can use `[hidden]` property to show or hide the element

[Refer this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42216265/2008962)

Comment: *ngIf is usually the cleanest way to completely remove it from padding, positioning, etc. The overhead isn't very high unless you put it on something with a serious amount of rendering (lots of children).

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 4 you can use ion-hide as well as add breakpoints to determine when to hide based on the screen width.

Be sure to have imported the proper css file to your global.css

```
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/display.css';
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#element-display